# How are kernel networking settings handled in OpenVZ containers?

Tags: linux-networking, openvz

I’m a little confused on how containers handle networking. For our normal systems, we’re enforcing things like Disable Source Routed Packet Acceptance, Disable Send Packet Redirects, etc. We usually enforce these via /etc/sysctl.conf, although they are typically backed up in /proc/sys/net/. Does setting network settings like that (things that affect /proc/sys/net) has any effect on individual containers? Does it matter? Does changing it in one container change it in the others running on that host?